# Pyspark: Iterate over groups in a dataframe

Tags: sql, dictionary, pyspark

I have the following dataframe ordered by two columns: `id` and `Updated_date`.

Initial dataframe:

```
       |id|date      |Updated_date       |
       |a |2019-02-14|2018-10-30 10:25:45|
       |a |2019-02-14|2018-11-28 10:51:34|
       |a |2019-01-11|2018-11-29 10:46:07|
       |a |2019-01-14|2018-11-30 10:42:56|
       |a |2019-01-16|2018-12-01 10:28:46|
       |a |2019-01-22|2018-12-02 10:22:06|
       |b |2019-01-25|2018-11-15 10:36:59|
       |b |2019-02-10|2018-11-16 10:58:01| 
       |b |2019-02-04|2018-11-17 10:42:12|
       |b |2019-02-10|2018-11-24 10:24:56|
       |b |2019-02-02|2018-12-01 10:28:46|
```

I want to create two new columns `LB`and `UB` in such a way that: 
for each `id`, the first values of `LB`and `UB`are the values of an interval of (date +/- 10 days), for the next values having the same `id`, we verify if the `date` is between `LB`and `UB` of the previous row, if yes we use the same values, if not we recompute a new interval of (+/- 10 days).

My expected output:

```
       |id|date      |Updated_date       |LB        |UB        |
       |a |2019-02-14|2018-10-30 10:25:45|2019-02-04|2019-02-24|
       |a |2019-02-14|2018-11-28 10:51:34|2019-02-04|2019-02-24|
       |a |2019-01-11|2018-11-29 10:46:07|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-14|2018-11-30 10:42:56|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-16|2018-12-01 10:28:46|2019-01-01|2019-01-21|
       |a |2019-01-22|2018-12-02 10:22:06|2019-01-12|2019-02-01|
       |b |2019-01-25|2018-11-15 10:36:59|2019-01-15|2019-02-04|
       |b |2019-02-10|2018-11-16 10:58:01|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
       |b |2019-02-04|2018-11-17 10:42:12|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
       |b |2019-02-10|2018-11-24 10:24:56|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
       |b |2019-02-02|2018-12-01 10:28:46|2019-02-01|2019-02-20|
```

How could I iterate over rows inside each group?

Comment: Someone asked this question some 2 days back. Search for it under 'PySpark' and you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with udf.

```
from datetime import timedelta

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

SS = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


data = [{"id": "a", "date": "2019-02-14", "updated_date": "2018-10-30 10:25:45"},
        {"id": "a", "date": "2019-02-14", "updated_date": "2018-11-28 10:51:34"},
        {"id": "a", "date": "2019-01-11", "updated_date": "2018-11-29 10:46:07"},
        {"id": "a", "date": "2019-01-14", "updated_date": "2018-11-30 10:42:56"},
        {"id": "a", "date": "2019-01-16", "updated_date": "2018-12-01 10:28:46"},
        {"id": "a", "date": "2019-01-22", "updated_date": "2018-12-02 10:22:06"},
        {"id": "b", "date": "2019-01-25", "updated_date": "2018-11-15 10:36:59"},
        {"id": "b", "date": "2019-02-10", "updated_date": "2018-11-16 10:58:01"},
        {"id": "b", "date": "2019-02-04", "updated_date": "2018-11-17 10:42:12"},
        {"id": "b", "date": "2019-02-10", "updated_date": "2018-11-24 10:24:56"},
        {"id": "b", "date": "2019-02-02", "updated_date": "2018-12-01 10:28:46"}]


schema = {
    "fields": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "date",
            "nullable": False,
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "id",
            "nullable": False,
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "updated_date",
            "nullable": False,
            "type": "timestamp"
        },

    ]
}

@udf("date")
def increment(cell):
    return cell+timedelta(days=10)


@udf("date")
def decrease(cell):
    return cell+timedelta(days=-10)

df = SS.createDataFrame(data)

for field in schema["fields"]:
    df = df.withColumn(field["name"], df[field["name"]].cast(field["type"]))

df.show()
df.printSchema()

df = df.withColumn("UB", increment("date"))
df = df.withColumn("LB", decrease("date"))

df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

My output:

```
# After aplying schema
+----------+---+-------------------+
|      date| id|       updated_date|
+----------+---+-------------------+
|2019-02-14|  a|2018-10-30 10:25:45|
|2019-02-14|  a|2018-11-28 10:51:34|
|2019-01-11|  a|2018-11-29 10:46:07|
|2019-01-14|  a|2018-11-30 10:42:56|
|2019-01-16|  a|2018-12-01 10:28:46|
|2019-01-22|  a|2018-12-02 10:22:06|
|2019-01-25|  b|2018-11-15 10:36:59|
|2019-02-10|  b|2018-11-16 10:58:01|
|2019-02-04|  b|2018-11-17 10:42:12|
|2019-02-10|  b|2018-11-24 10:24:56|
|2019-02-02|  b|2018-12-01 10:28:46|
+----------+---+-------------------+

root
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- updated_date: timestamp (nullable = true)


+----------+---+-------------------+----------+----------+
|      date| id|       updated_date|        UB|        LB|
+----------+---+-------------------+----------+----------+
|2019-02-14|  a|2018-10-30 10:25:45|2019-02-24|2019-02-04|
|2019-02-14|  a|2018-11-28 10:51:34|2019-02-24|2019-02-04|
|2019-01-11|  a|2018-11-29 10:46:07|2019-01-21|2019-01-01|
|2019-01-14|  a|2018-11-30 10:42:56|2019-01-24|2019-01-04|
|2019-01-16|  a|2018-12-01 10:28:46|2019-01-26|2019-01-06|
|2019-01-22|  a|2018-12-02 10:22:06|2019-02-01|2019-01-12|
|2019-01-25|  b|2018-11-15 10:36:59|2019-02-04|2019-01-15|
|2019-02-10|  b|2018-11-16 10:58:01|2019-02-20|2019-01-31|
|2019-02-04|  b|2018-11-17 10:42:12|2019-02-14|2019-01-25|
|2019-02-10|  b|2018-11-24 10:24:56|2019-02-20|2019-01-31|
|2019-02-02|  b|2018-12-01 10:28:46|2019-02-12|2019-01-23|
+----------+---+-------------------+----------+----------+

root
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- updated_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- UB: date (nullable = true)
```